# Get path of "setup.exe" from running MSI package

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action

Is it possible to get the path of the executable package (aka bootstrapper) that started an MSI installation, from within a custom action?

The regular way of getting parent process of DLL won't work, because custom action DLL gets loaded by "msiexec.exe", not by the bootstrapper.exe. Parent process of "msiexec.exe" is "services.exe", so that won't help either.

Msiexec.exe seems to know about calling process, because it writes this line into the log file:

```
=== Verbose logging started: [blah...] Calling process: C:\temp\testsetup.exe ===
```

I couldn't find any API to query this information though. I looked into [property reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx) and [installer functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369426(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Which tool are you using to build your setup.exe and MSI? Most will do this but they are not all the same.

Comment: "setup.exe" is a custom application written in C++, MSI is build via [python msilib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msilib.html). I can't modify either of them because I'm just providing a merge module. I need to read some data appended to the "setup.exe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up modifying the bootstrapper setup.exe to pass its own path to the MSI package.

1. Bootstrapper calls [`GetModuleFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew) to determine its own path.
2. Bootstrapper calls [`MsiInstallProduct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msi/nf-msi-msiinstallproductw), passing the path as command-line argument.

   ```
   std::wstring cmdLine = L"BOOTSTRAPPER_PATH=\"" + executablePath + L"\"";
   MsiInstallProduct( msiFilePath.c_str(), cmdLine.c_str() );
   ```
3. Custom action calls [`MsiGetProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msiquery/nf-msiquery-msigetpropertyw) to read the value of `BOOTSTRAPPER_PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your setup.exe is in the same location as your MSI file, the SourceDir property tells you the folder that the MSI is being installed from. The OriginalDatabase property tells you the full path to the MSI files.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371857(v=vs.85).aspx

If the setup.exe actually initiates the MSI file from a well-know location, it might be one of the other standard properties such as TempFolder. But there is no reason why you can't just pass the folder into the MSI install. If you declare a public secure property in your MSI called (say) MYFOLDER then just start the MSI with a command line including MYFOLDER=[path name]

I'm assuming you know how to get property values from within custom actions.

It is not a good idea to install an MSI from a temp location where it may be removed from. The recommendation is to keep the MSI available, Rule 31:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_installer_team/2006/05/24/tao-of-the-windows-installer-part-3/

Comment: _Assuming that your setup.exe is in the same location as your MSI file_ - Unfortunately it's not. The setup.exe is a self-extracting executable that will extract the MSI file into a temp directory.